# Reverse Structure Position XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I would like some tips to finish the reverse structure:

*The `XML` was edited it's too large to post here*

Input as you can see below there is `Header` and `Body`, `body` there are `EvenList`, `ObjectEvent` and `AggregationEvent`

Input XML:

```
<Document>
  <Header />
<Body>
    <EventList>
        --> <ObjectEvent>
            --> <eventTime>2018-09-06T08:51:24Z</eventTime>
        --> </ObjectEvent>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <eventTime>2018-09-06T08:51:24Z</eventTime>
        </AggregationEvent>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <eventTime>2018-09-06T08:51:24Z</eventTime>
        </AggregationEvent>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <eventTime>2018-09-06T08:51:24Z</eventTime>
        </AggregationEvent>
    </EventList>
</Body>
</Document>
```

Expected Output `XML` - The `XSLT` Program need reverse the position of `ObjectEvent` to the last `AggregationEvent`.

```
    <Document>
  <Header />
<Body>
    <EventList>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <eventTime>2018-09-06T08:51:25Z</eventTime>
        </AggregationEvent>
        <AggregationEvent>
            <eventTime>2018-09-06T08:51:25Z</eventTime>
        </AggregationEvent>
        --> <ObjectEvent>
            --> <eventTime>2018-09-06T08:51:24Z</eventTime>
        --> </ObjectEvent>
    </EventList>
</Body>
</Document>
```

Start point `XSLT` without required logic:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//AggregationEvent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for the inputs.

Regards,

Comment: ...and you certainly have some XSLT to show, as well?

Comment: i don't. I just start something I post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started in the right way, by using the identity template. What you should be doing on the other template though is matching on the parent `EventList` and then selecting the child nodes in the order you like.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EventList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="AggregationEvent" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ObjectEvent" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you were using XSLT 2.0, you could simply the two `xsl:apply-templates` into one, by doing this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="AggregationEvent, ObjectEvent" />
```

And if you were using XSLT 3.0, you could replace the identity template with this...

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

Comment: Tim once again, thanks ! It's works as need. Kind Regards.